# Assign value from one data.frame to a specific column of another data.frame in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, select, replace, tidyverse

I would like to replace the first value of column `Z` of `DF2` with the last value of column `B` of `DF1`. I want to make it general, that means, instead of specifying the last row (row number 10) of `DF1` column `B`, is there a way to use `end` or anything else that would grab the last value of a particular column (in this case column `B` of `DF1`).

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(1500)

DF1 <- data.frame(A = runif(10,1,5), B = runif(10,5,10))
DF2 <- data.frame(X = runif(10,1,5), Z = runif(10,5,10))

DF2[1,2] <- DF1$B[10, 2]
```

Comment: I guess you meant `DF2$Z[1] <- DF1$B[10]`. When you extract a vector `DF1$B`, there is no dim attribute. Or use index.  `DF2[[2]][1] <- DF1[[2]][nrow(DF1)]`

Comment: Yes, exactly. thanks. is there a way to avoid specifying the row number in `DF1$B[10]` ?

Comment: You can use `nrow` in my updated comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this can help you:

```
DF2$Z[1]<-DF1$B[dim(DF1)[1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `nrow(DF1)`.  Either extract using the column index or column name with `[[` and then with numeric index for first (`1`) and last (`nrow`), do the assignment

```
DF2[[2]][1] <- DF1[[2]][nrow(DF1)]
```